# Best way to integrate "Help Guide" into a Android Application

Tags: android, help

I would like introduce some "help" into my Android application to provide user some source of FAQ/this icon is what/how-to for features in my Android application.

Most android applications I seen seem to favor adding a "Help" under the Menu which will link to their help guide main landing page. The user then needs to search for the topic they need help on.

I'm thinking of something along the same line, but perhaps based on the current page in the android app the user is on, I will redirect to a specific section of the help guide to fasten the help search process a little bit.

Are they any other ways to do it (pdf, video, etc) and what is currently the best practice to implement such the "help" inside a Android application?

Answer (score 2):

Tips / help or an onboarding sequence should only be employed if necessary - so as not to interrupt users - but when used appropriately they can guide the user in their initial experience and adoption.

**If the app supports tips / help, they are displayed in context to what the user is doing.**

If the user needs to learn anything about the app, but not before their first use of it, provide contextual tips and help instead of an onboarding sequence. Tips and help that are relevant to what the user is trying to do, when they are doing it, will be more beneficial to the user than a generic - and interruptive - onboarding. Engage users through images, animation and interactivity, to help them learn by doing, and only provide tips for priority or difficult tasks.

---

This is an iOS screen, but it will help you understand the thought behind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to have in-app help guide rather than directing him to a documentation page like this.
if you have more information give him in different steps.
this is something similar to POST SIGNUP process. but the user should be able to see it whenever he needs it.

[image]